# Addition of themes for Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, design

Since there already seem to be ways to do this with user-specific CSS: why not have a couple of base themes for the sites? I'd like to see a theme like the dark flair that is available.

Getting into the more unlikely, what about a way for users to choose their own colors? I know this site is more for questions and the like, but customizability never hurt anyone :P

Comment: Don't take it the wrong way, but this is StackOverflow, not MySpace.

Comment: You said it yourself - users who want this can already have it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So your logic is, "Those who really want it already have this ability, therefore the developers and designers should spend time implementing it for those who don't care"?

Hmmm...

I think I'd rather see a more mobile-friendly layout. Userstyles and Greasemonkey don't really help for that.

Answer (score 9):

Themes and skins are what developers add to a product when they run out of real feature ideas.

Answer (score 3):

I think this would add more complexity than is warranted by the increase in utility. We could wind up with lots of little things not looking quite right only on certain themes, leading to a less satisfying experience and distracting the developers from other tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't seem to agree with the majority here, but I think this could really be useful, and not at all a waste of time.

I found this question when looking around for a way of giving SO a dark theme (without having to implement this myself) so it wouldn't hurt my eyes when switching from my dark and nice Visual Studio theme. Given the opportunity, I think there are lots of SO users who would enjoy this.

*Note: If the developer team wants to implement more themes than this, it's up to them. The purpose of this is **not** to make SO look like MySpace - the selected theme would affect the appearance on **your own computer only**, and anyone who doesn't choose a non-default theme will have the same look as always before.*