# Is there any theming support?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Addition of themes for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57792/addition-of-themes-for-stack-overflow)

Is there any way to change the default Stack Overflow colors and to keep that colors linked to my account?

What I have in mind is something like Twitter themes.

Comment: http://stylebot.me/

Comment: Why did you give me downvotes?

Comment: Downvotes on meta means disagreement.

Comment: I see. Thanks @Gamecat

Answer (score 7):

Theme support might be nice & fun for a while, but I don't think it would be actually *useful* to anyone. I mean, what's the point? Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a social network.

If you really want a custom Stack Overflow theme, you can always write a basic userscript for it. Check out [StackExchange Theme Switcher](https://stackapps.com/questions/2808/stackexchange-theme-switcher) for inspiration.