# "Does this feature exist" counts as "I request this feature"?

Tags: discussion, questions, meta

[Is there any theming support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142514/is-there-any-theming-support)

This question simply *asks* if a feature exists and gets seven downvotes. The comment on the question says the downvotes are out of disagreement even though **no opinion was expressed** so there was nothing to disagree with.

Is the commenter providing misinformation by implying that you can disagree with a question, or is it normal for questions to be penalized for asking if an unpopular feature exists? I've asked such questions without penaty, so this is a matter of interpreting contradictory messages I've seen in the community.

Comment: `this is a matter of interpreting contradictory messages I've seen in the community.` yup, that's probably the essence of it. I assume the downvotes mean "I don't want theming, and I'm voting as if this were a feature request". Meta doesn't always make sense.

Comment: While I actually agree that people seem to get confused on this point, the OP complicated the matter a bit in this case by tagging the question [meta-tag:feature-request] instead of [meta-tag:support].

Comment: @TimStone good catch; I didn't notice the tag.

Answer (score 5):

When you post a feature request. Other users can express their opinions.

- Upvote:  I like the idea.
- Downvote: I don't like the idea.

Comment: This answer makes sense to me only after someone else pointed out that the question was tagged as a feature request. I took the question at face value based on its text and would have considered "feature request" a mistag that shouldn't determine the intent of the question.

Comment: Feature request ==  "I have an idea and I like to have it implemented on the SE network."

Comment: I didn't ask what a feature request is. I missed the fact that a question was tagged as a feature request. My question has already been answered, so thanks.