# Change background color of the Favorite-tags questions

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Addition of themes for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57792/addition-of-themes-for-stack-overflow)

Questions tagged with favorite tags are orange (`#ffefc6`). I would like to change that - is it possible?

Of course I could change the Chrome user stylesheet to force my own background, but that would only work on Chrome, and would have to be done on all computers.

*edit*

For info this is what I came up with on Chrome

```
#question-mini-list .tagged-interesting { background-color:#fffaf5 ! important;border:1px solid #eee ! important; }
```

(in `Google/Chrome/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css` on Mac / Linux)

Comment: No, it's not possible with any settings on the site itself.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not support themes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use custom css in your browser:

```
.tagged-interesting { 
  background-color: your-color;
}
```

Opera for instance lets you set [custom styles](http://www.opera.com/docs/usercss/) for every site but I am sure, other browsers also provide that functionality (at least via plugin).